# How to pass special character "(hyphen) -" inside template literal

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Amateur ReactNative Developer, How do i pass special character Hyphen (-) inside template literal. In this way `${hyphen inside}`
For say:

```
<Component text = `${this.props.color}` />
```

So how do i edit in such a way that whenever color is passed. It passes in this way: "-Green"

Comment: No i don't want it that way..I am asking is it possible to pass "-" inside that template literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do normal JavaScript operations inside template literal curly brackets, for example:

`${color ? ('-' + color) : null}`.

---

Your example:

```js
//                 if color exists   ?   return "-color"   :    else nothing
<Component text =`${this.props.color ? ("-" + this.props.color) : null}` />
```

Comment: Can i add hyphen in this similar way, `${("-")this.props.color}`

Comment: No, it's normal JavaScript: you need to check the condition if you want to apply something based on a condition. My example translates to `condition ? (if condition is truthy, do this) : (else, do this)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you're saying is not possible, however you could alter the prop you're sending as such (let's say you have **{0}** as a placeholder :

```
`${this.props.color.replace('{0}', '-')}`
```

in case it's a **string**.Maybe you have a specific use case you need help with, add it to your question.

Another example:

```
`${'-'.concat(this.props.color)}`
```

would result in (assuming this.props.color is 'Green') "-Green"

Comment: Can you make it more simpler as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you already store hype(any variable) in props like : this.props.hyp = "-" then use:

```
<Component text = `${this.props.hyp}` />
```

else use simply this:

```
<Component text = `-`/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the character outside of `${...}` like

```
<Component text = `-${this.props.color}` />
```

See a demo snippet

```js
var data = "Green"

console.log(`-${data}`);
```

In case you want to pass text a value only when `this.props.color is` available, you can make use of `ternary operator` like

```
<Component text = {this.props.color? `-${this.props.color}`: null} />
```

Comment: Yes that is 1 way of doing, but i want to show that hyphen only when some color is passed. Since you defined that hyphen outside of dollar it will render everytime..So is there a way to pass hyphen inside ${ } itself ?

Comment: @Hash , Everything that is within `${}` is resolved so you cannot pass that inside of `${}` but you can have a ternary condition. I will add that